# Oracle - select rows with minimal value in a subset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a following table of dates:

```
dateID INT (PK),
personID INT (FK),
date DATE,
starttime VARCHAR, --Always in a format of 'HH:MM'
```

What I want to do is I want to pull rows (all columns, including PK) with lowest date (primary condition) and starttime (secondary condition) for every person. For example, if we have

row1(date = '2013-04-01' and starttime = '14:00')

and

row2(date = '2013-04-02' and starttime = '08:00')

row1 will be retrieved, along with all other columns.

So far I have come up with gradual filtering the table, but it`s quite a mess. Is there more efficient way of doing this?

Here is what I made so far:

```
    SELECT 
    D.id
    , D.personid
    , D.date        
    , D.starttime 
FROM table D 
JOIN (
        SELECT --Select lowest time from the subset of lowest dates
            A.personid, 
            B.startdate, 
            MIN(A.starttime) AS starttime 
        FROM table A 
        JOIN (
                SELECT --Select lowest date for every person to exclude them from outer table
                    personid
                    , MIN(date) AS startdate
                FROM table
                GROUP BY personid
            ) B
        ON A.personid = B.peronid
        AND A.date = B.startdate
        GROUP BY 
            A.personid, 
            B.startdate
    ) C
ON C.personid = D.personid
AND C.startdate = D.date 
AND C.starttime = D.starttime
```

It works, but I think there is a more clean/efficient way to do this. Any ideas?

EDIT: Let me expand a question - I also need to extract maximum date (only date, without time) for each person.

The result should look like this:

```
id
personid
max(date) for each person
min(date) for each person
min(starttime) for min(date) for each person
```

It is a part of a much larger query (the resulting table is joined with it), and the resulting table must be lightweight enough so that the query won`t execute for too long. With single join with this table (just using min, max for each field I wanted) the query took about 3 seconds, and I would like the resulting query not to take longer than 2-3 times that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to do this like:

```
select a.dateID, a.personID, a.date, a.max_date, a.starttime
  from (select t.*, 
               max(t.date) over (partition by t.personID) max_date,
               row_number() over (partition by t.personID 
                                  order by t.date, t.starttime) rn
          from table t) a
 where a.rn = 1;
```

sample data added to fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63c45/1

Comment: The answer is nice, but it is very ineffective when combined with the rest of my query.

Comment: @kyooryu perhaps if you showed the rest of your query? as what you posted, is the same as the answer i provided in terms of results. you can alter the fiddle example and post the fiddle here for us to see.

Comment: I`m afraid I can`t show much more of the query than I already posted. I expanded the question a bit though, so you can see what is the result I`ll be joining the the rest of the query.

Comment: @kyooryu ok, so all that is missing form the query i provided is max(dte) for a person , right (as a.date is really the min date). see edit

Comment: The performance is more or less satisfactory with this solution, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you can use and no need to incorporate in your query. You can also use @Dazzal's query as stand alone

```
SELECT ID, PERSONID, DATE, STARTTIME
(
SELECT ID, PERONID, DATE, STARTTIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY     STARTTIME, DATE) AS RN
FROM TABLE 
) A
WHERE 
RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id,a.accomp, a.accomp_name, a.start_year,a.end_year, a.company
  from (select t.*, 
               min(t.start_year) over (partition by t.company) min_date,
               max(t.end_year) over (partition by t.company) max_date,
               row_number() over (partition by t.company 
                                  order by t.end_year desc) rn
          from temp_123 t) a
 where a.rn = 1;
```